# Python RegEx: Extract timestamp between Square brackets

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a source data which is given below:-

```
14.284.2.1572 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
187.109.797.1798 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
16.197.978.107 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
190.392.905.549 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
```

I wanted to extract data between **square brackets** example `21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700` .

I am written a regex code but it looks not optimum, can we have a better way to achieve desired result.

```
re.findall(r"([0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s-[0-9]{4})", data)
```

I have also tried with `?<=` and `?=`, but problem is special characters in data.
Any suggestion or input will be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you can't just match anything in square brackets like `r"(\[.*\])"`? Unless you're expecting other square brackets to pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you've been looking for: `re.findall(r"(?<=\[).*(?=\])", data)`; returns `['21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700']` for your first line.

Another option would be to try using `.split()` like `data.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]`

Comment: can plz explain me what does ```.*?``` mean between 2 groups ?

Comment: This was a mistake, you can remove the question mark and only use `.*` between them - which means any character (`.`) repeated 0-unlimited times (`*`).

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your regex pattern and just match a leading IP address, followed by dash, a username, and then a timestamp term inside square brackets.

```py
inp = """14.284.2.1572 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
187.109.797.1798 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
16.197.978.107 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
190.392.905.549 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048"""

timestamps = re.findall(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+){3} - \w+ \[(.*?)\]', inp, flags=re.M)
print(timestamps)
```

This prints:

```
[
    '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
    '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700',
    '21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700',
    '21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700'
]
```